# Caliburn.Micro - IoC is not initialized

Tags: ioc-container, caliburn.micro

In my Windows Phone 8.1 application (native, non-silverlight) I'm using Caliburn.Micro.
In some part  of my application I have to use *service locator* instead of *constructor injection*, so I'm calling this:

```
var service = IoC.Get<ITestClass>();
```

But when I call it, I get:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Caliburn.Micro.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: IoC is not initialized.
```

My initialization class is:

```
public sealed partial class App
{
    private WinRTContainer container;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    } 

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new WinRTContainer();
        container.RegisterWinRTServices();

        Register(container);

        IoC.GetInstance = this.GetInstance;
        IoC.GetAllInstances = this.GetAllInstances;
        IoC.BuildUp = this.BuildUp;
    }

    private void Register(WinRTContainer container)
    {
        // Automatically register all view models
        foreach(var type in typeof(ViewModelBase).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ViewModelBase))))
        {
            if (type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract)
            {
                container.RegisterPerRequest(type.ImplementedInterfaces.Count() == 1 ? type.ImplementedInterfaces.First() : type.AsType(), null, type.AsType());
            }
        }

        container.PerRequest<ITestClass, TestClass>();
        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ResourceLoader), "ResourceLoader", new ResourceLoader());
    } 

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        #if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
        #endif
        DisplayRootView<MainPageView>();
    } 

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return container.GetInstance(service, key);
    } 

    protected override void PrepareViewFirst(Frame rootFrame)
    {
        container.RegisterNavigationService(rootFrame);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return container.GetAllInstances(service);
    } 

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.BuildUp(instance);
    } 
}
```

**EDIT:**
Problem is that I call the *IoC.Get< ITest>()* metod in the implementation of IBackgroundTask. And on another thread the property *IoC.GetInstance* is null again. Why?

Thanks

Comment: you shouldn't have to explicitly initialize the IoC, it is part of the StartRuntime method in the CaliburnApplication.  In a sense you are doing it twice, with your current Configure method.

Comment: No, the problem was, that I wanted to call IoC.Get<ITestService>() in the IBackgroundTask implementation, where all static fields are empty.